# Limit of cube root, Conjugate?

Tags: limits

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}(n^2 + \root3\of{n^4-n^6}).$$

I tried to solve this but I guess I need to do it with conjugate, which I can't say I understand it well, I need some help.

Comment: Use that $x^3-y^3=(x-y)(\cdots)$

Comment: @Martín-Blas Pérez Pinilla: I think you made a mistake in editing: it was a +, not a - between the terms. Apparently I can't just change the sign...

Comment: Note that $x^3 + y^3 = (x + y)(x^2 - xy + y^2)$.

Comment: @StackTD, true. In any case, the idea is using the factorization $x^3\pm y^3 = (x\pm y)(\cdots)$.

Comment: Yes of course! I only made the remark because I wasn't able to do the edit myself, perhaps you could re-edit your edit... :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make use of the identity $(a+b)(a^2-ab+b^2)=a^3+b^3$ with, in your case, $a=n^2$ and $b=\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}$. You already have the $(a-b)$ part, complete the product by adding the factor $a^2-ab+b^2$ in numerator and denominator.

$$n^2+\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6} = \frac{\left( n^2+\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6} \right)\left( \cdots \right)}{ \cdots }$$

Can you take it from here?

*Addition* (after comment): the denominator becomes
$$(n^2)^2-n^2\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}+\left(\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}\right)^2$$

Bring out the highest powers in $n$ to get a common factor $n^4$:
$$n^4-n^4\sqrt[3]{n^{-2}-1}+n^4\left(\sqrt[3]{n^{-2}-1}\right)^2$$

Simplify by canceling the $n^4$ in numerator and denominator.

Comment: I did what you said and the result was 1, what do you think?

Comment: Are you sure? The numerator should simplify to just $n^4$ (did you get that?) and in the denominator, you should find three terms of the order of $n^4$... I find 1/3.

Comment: I got n^4 in the numerator but in denominator i get n^3-n, i got that from (n^2)^2-n^2*cube root n^4-n^6 + (cube root n^4-n^6)^2 which comes from a^2-ab+b^2. I see i made a mistake at b^2 but i don't know what to do with it.

Comment: I added some help with the denominator in my answer.

Comment: n^4-n^4*-1+n^4*(-1)^2=n^4+n^4+n^4=3n^4.......n^4/3n^4=1/3..

Comment: Well yes, that's more or less the idea. You should try to write it out properly, but you'll get 1/3 indeed.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the conjugate is the correct idea.  However, the conjugate that you might be thinking of, $n^2-\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}$ will make things a mess.  Instead, you want to use 
$$n^4-n^2\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}+\left(\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}\right)^2.$$

This is because $$\left(n^2+\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}\right)\left(n^4-n^2\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}+\left(\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}\right)^2\right)=n^6+\left(\sqrt[3]{n^4-n^6}\right)^3=n^4.$$